# MSP430 msp430-gbd doesn't debug the fine value

Tags: c, msp430

I have a question about MSP430 launchpad of TI (1.5 with MSP430g2553).

If I prog the mcu with the following hello work code, I have some issues to read the fine values with gdb in debugg mode.

```
#include <msp430g2553.h>
**const int titi = 3;//Global variable**

int main(){
    WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;                

    P1DIR = 0x41;
    **int tata = 0x1;//first local variable**

    while(1){
        P1OUT = 0x41;
        **int toto = 10;//Second local variable**
        __delay_cycles(99999);
        P1OUT=~0x41;
        int tyty = 20;
        __delay_cycles(99999);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

1. gcc is using to download the code througth the mcu : *$ make prog v=main.c*
2. **$ mspdebug rf2500 gdb** and  *msp430-gdb main.elf*
3. *target remote localhost:2000*

led are blinking. after a few tiem I stop the execution and I ask the local variables :
    (gdb) info locals
    toto = 1
    tyty = 10
    tata = -577

No issue with information about global variable **titi**. **toto** and **tyty** are the values which appear in my code, but that is a different value for **tata**. Why ?

don't think that is a bug of gdb....

Best regards,

GM

Comment: Probably because it was never used. Do something with it, or compile without optimizations.